# null object reference on getView Method

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I know this types of error already has been answered. But i am not able figure out the cause of error. what i am trying to accomplish is to add button dynamically into fragment from a button click which is in main activity. please help me. i am new to android development,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button add;
Fragment f;
LinearLayout ll;
View v;

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addButton);

    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            f = (ButtonFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.buttonLayout);
            //if (f != null) {
                v = f.getView();
                ll = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonLayout);
                Button dummy = new Button(v.getContext());
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(70, 70);
                dummy.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                ll.addView(dummy);
            //} else {
              //  System.out.println("View is null");
            //}

        }
    });
}


}
```

**This is the fragment class**

```
public class ButtonFragment extends Fragment {


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_button, container, false);
    return rootView;
}
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   System.out.println("View created");
}
}
```

**this are the error code**

> 11-25 23:15:15.442 987-987/com.example.nekib.dynamiclayoutdemo
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                    Process: com.example.nekib.dynamiclayoutdemo, PID: 987
>                                                                                    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.view.View android.app.Fragment.getView()' on a null object
>   reference
>                                                                                        at
>   com.example.nekib.dynamiclayoutdemo.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:33)
>                                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
>                                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                        at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

Comment: could you please help me to solve the problem

Comment: Did you declare this fragment in XML? Cause i don't see any runtime initialization .

Comment: yes i did it in xml file

Comment: Post you xml here .Beside that Thats a awkward way to use of fragment .

Answer (score 1):

You are finding a fragment that is never initiated. You are just finding it and getting its view. Fragment was never created so it has null view.

By the way correct way to replace fragments is as following.

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
Fragment fragment = new FragmentProfile();
ft.replace(R.id.main_frame_container, fragment, fragmentName.toString());
ft.commit();
```

Here `main_frame_container` is `FrameLayout` in Activity's layout.

Use this method to replace or adding fragments on a view.

Comment: i am not replacing any fragment. just adding button from main activity

Comment: then can you tell me how to initiate a fragment

Comment: I am working in android from 2 years bro, i never used any method to make a button like this.

Comment: Edit your post and post your requirement so that i can tell you solution

Comment: just tell me how to get the layout of fragment in main activity please

Comment: You can directly get layout from xml folder, why are you pointing fragment. So i want know what you have to do. So i can tell you best solution for that.

Comment: The Fragment can be added from the XML, not needed to use Fragment transactions

Answer (score -2):

First `R.id.buttonLayout` cannot be both a Fragment ID and a LinearLayout inside the Fragment

More importantly, you need to use `getSupportFragmentManager()` if you're using Support Fragment classes. Look at your `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment`

Besides that, though, you probably shouldn't have the button in the Activity to control the Fragment layout

Comment: Why it has -1 ? it should work...

Comment: why should not i do that

Comment: it is not Support Fragment classes

Comment: Lol, then it will not work with AppCompatActivity

Comment: @NEK Your Fragment is supposed to be a separate, self contained entity from the Activity. By adding views to the Fragment from the Activity is just a bad design in Android development. Besides, your code errors at `findFragmentById`, so you should try something much different until you understand how that method works

Comment: i know that its a bad practice. but can you tell me how to achieve such technique

Comment: First of all, did you try moving your button into the Fragment?